# How to calculate mean from hundreds of rasters in R

Tags: loops, gis, mean, raster

I have a folder of ~39,000 raster files (.tif format). Each raster has NDVI of a day at a nest box location (440 total) in a buffer in either 2022 or 2023. I want to calculate the average NDVI at each nest box for each year. The naming convention of the files is like so:

443_AKWI314_MAS_2022.0_20230805_163848_92_2484_3B_AnalyticMS_SR_clip_ndvi

```
443 = FID
AKWI314 = Nest box name (unique)
MAS = project
20230805 = date of NDVI
```

What code can I use to sort through so much data without having to load in every .tif? Is there a way to loop through all the files and generate an average per nest box per year (2022 or 2023) given this naming convention? This data was generated by someone else, and I'm lost as to how to go about this. TIA!!!

I have tried messing around with the raster package, but the sorting and looping is daunting.